I have a created a login/signup using otp .spring validations are not working such as not blank and size
I have a created a login using otp with twlio. I have put validation such as not empty and size but validations are not working. Whenver I run the code without putting any phone number, valdiation does not work.
This is the entity code
  @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 15)
    private String mobileNumber;

This is the send otp code
   @PostMapping("/sendotp")
    public String sendotp(@Valid @RequestParam String mobileNumber, @ModelAttribute("phoneNo") PhoneNo phoneNo,
            BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "modalnumber";
        }
        model.addAttribute("phoneNo", phoneNo);
        return otpService.generateOtp(mobileNumber);

When I try to submit without an input number, it should show:

Please enter valid number

The regex pattern


But it shows nothing.

When you say validations are not working, what output are you getting exactly when you make an actual API call to /sendOtp enpoint ?

@prashant parapelli  Spring uses the Valid annotation to trigger validation on the annotated object, such as an entity or DTO. To validate a String, you need to use specific annotations like Size directly on the field within the DTO. This way, Spring knows which validation rules to apply.

@rootExplorr i am getting error as could not commit jpa transaction

@kushparsaniya i have applied size and not empty directly on the filed

No you have applied Size annotation on entity, but you are using @Valid on String, you have to use Valid on entity not on String. if you applied Valid on String how does spring know which Validation to use there can be multiple field of type string in your whole project that has Size applied.

public class PhoneNo {     @Id     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)     private int id;     @NotBlank     @Size(min = 2, max = 15)     private String mobileNumber; } @kushparsaniya

You have to use  public String sendotp(@Valid @RequestParam PhoneNo phoneNo) than it will work not directly on string.
